# Explanation as to why aidl seems to be included automatically in

Tags: android, aidl

I'm still a newbie to Android.  I have been focussing on Audio/Video support.  When I import certain projects into Android Studio one of the biggest issues I run into is:

```
 ':Application:compileDebugAidl'
  >aidl is missing.
```

OK, I've read about AIDL on the Android APIs Guide web page. And noted the application of AIDL when concurrent IPC is required across different applications.

1. Why is aidl even being included in an imported project when the application is not using it?
   It seems related to debugging
2. But does that mean I have write  to extra code for debugging within Android Studio?

I've run into this several times and have been able to "get the project to compile" but I figured it's time to put time into understanding what is going on.

Comment: Do you have any .aidl files in your converted project?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to concern yourself with AIDL if you didn't define a Service in your AndroidManifest.xml that has a remote interface intent-filter.  If you are curious about seeing AIDL in action, then look at SDK sample for Services in /legacy/ApiDemos directory.

But if you are still getting this compile error, then you should go ahead and post your **build.gradle** file here for us to inspect.